# Can you tell me how to make equal spacing above and below my homepage gallery

Tags: css, gallery, space, temp

[image]Im using a template based site, with added css. So I dont have any code to add, other than below. Here is my [site](http://jeffreydowellphotography.com) im trying to fix.
The code below is what i added to fix the spacing above my homepage gallery, and it messed up the space below the gallery. Im trying to make the top and bottom equal space.

```
.sqs-layout .sqs-row .sqs-block:last-child {
 padding-bottom: 34;
 padding-top: 0;
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - do you want the 'footer' section (with the social icons and copyright) to be at the bottom of the page?

Comment: I would like the area with the arrows to match the area where the star is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the CSS `#pageWrapper{margin-bottom:30px;}` which displays normally at big screen sizes. However, that space is still there when you resize the window.

The solution is to add `margin-bottom:0px;` into the `@media` thing:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px)
#header, #pageWrapper, #footer{
padding: 30px 20px;
margin-bottom:0px;
}
```

EDIT:
`margin-bottom: 0px !important` in the `@media` query should do it.

Comment: it equaled the space, but made it too huge. I tried adjusting the numbers, and it didnt help